# How to change the hint size of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, hint, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

This is my xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/main_input_text"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_medium_margin"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    style="@style/main_edit_text"
                    android:inputType="text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is style

```
<style name="main_input_text">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/activity_edittext_height</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/mc_shape_border_button_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_extra_small_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_extra_small_margin</item>
        <item name="android:keyTextSize">8sp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item>
</style>
```

I don't find something like hintSize, textSize and keyTextSize not helping

Answer (score 146, accepted):

In your styles.xml

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

And then in your layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
         app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
         android:minHeight="30dp">
```

Comment: This style not working when there is no text in edittext (inside TextInputLayout).

Comment: @NeerajBagra It seems that hint's color in an unfocused style must be set by the `android:textColorHint` attribute

Answer (score 9):

Change the TextInputLayout's `app:errorTextAppearance` in XML.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextInputLayoutStyle.ErrorTextStyle">
```

Where `CustomTextInputLayoutStyle.ErrorTextStyle` is defined in `styles.xml` as

```
<style name="CustomTextInputLayoutStyle.ErrorTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

@Santiago Martínez answer only works for hints on non empty `Edittext` (inside `TextInputLayout`)

But for empty `Edittext`, `TextInputLayout` hint takes property from `Edittext` `textSize`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Add `hintTextAppearance` to your InputLayout with a style

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutHintText" >
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"              
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

2) Then just add the style to your styles.xml

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutHintText">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item></style>
```

Answer (score 2):

For `material 1.4.0`

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`

You only need to change the `android:textSize` attribute for the `TextInputEditText` for the hint size to change.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can reduce the font size on the EditText - that will reduce the size of the hint as well. i.e. android:textSize="16sp"

Comment: The problem is that i whant to make edit text size biger and hint smaller.

Comment: Anyway it is not worked. Hint size only increased in `EditText`, not in `TextInputLayout`.